# How best to trigger function that is inside a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function

I am tying to trigger a function that is inside a Movie Clip

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myfuntion);

    function myfuntion(myEvent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(44);
        tvscreen_mc.function("byby");

    }
```

the byby function is inside tvscreen_mc

```
function byby(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {        
my_player.destroy();    

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myfuntion);

    function myfuntion(myEvent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(44);
        tvscreen_mc.function("byby");

    }
```

with

`MovieClip(root).my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MovieClip(root).tvscreen_mc.byby);`

this will also work, if you're at the root level (which I assume you are, but incase you put it somewhere else):

`my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tvscreen_mc.byby);`

Comment: Im trying to have function "byby" fire on click of "my_mc" it looks like this codes adding a new lister for tvscreen_mc ? or am I way off?